# can't import gradle constraintlayout 2.0

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I've tried to import constraintlayout 2.0 but didn't succeed
If tried importing it into gradle but it can't resolve it. but if I import constraintlayout 1.1.0 it works like a charm

works:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

not works:

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.+'
```

in order to try the new constraintlayout, I've installed android studio 3.2. I also have the latest tools that come with it.
I've checked the sdk tools and I can't see constraintlayout 2.0 under support repositories.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.pteran_pc.test28"
        minSdkVersion 'P'
        targetSdkVersion 'P'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.+'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha1'
}
```

the main build gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-alpha14'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I do not see anything for that listed at https://maven.google.com. Are you sure that they have released an alpha of `ConstraintLayout` 2.0?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but taking in to account that they have already promoted it on the google IO i suppossed that there should be an alpha available for early adopters at least

Comment: My interpretation of [this tweet](https://twitter.com/camaelon/status/995739466219192320) from the `ConstraintLayout` lead would suggest that they have not published an alpha yet.

Comment: you seems to be right!! how sad :( :(

Comment: It may be that they hoped to have an alpha ready by the time of I|O, but the schedule slipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alpha version is available now :)

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha1'
```

https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2018/06/constraintlayout-200-alpha-1.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [Android Studio Release Updates' webpage](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/) the most recent version available for `ConstraintLayout` is `1.1.0`

So I think it's safe to think that `ConstraintLayout 2.0` is not available yet.

Comment: Yes, it seems so, but taking in consideration that they published it on the google IO I supposed that constraintlayout 2.0 should be at least in alpha for early adopters

Comment: I think @CommonsWare is right. Maybe they were planning to have it ready for the I/O but couldn't make it on time